# What can I do to use a hook inside a function?

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a Logout function when the token has expired. There is an `AuthProvider` in my application:

```
const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState({ token: localStorage.getItem("access_token") });

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
```

Now that the token has expired I need to call the `setAuth` hook and write an empty token there:

```
const logout = () =>{
  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
      withCredentials: true
  })
  axiosInstance.get("http://localhost:8080/api/auth/logout")
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.config);
    });
    window.location.href = '/auth'
};

const Logout = () => {
  const {auth,setAuth} = useAuth();
  const token = '';
  setAuth({token});
  localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
  localStorage.clear();
  logout()
};

export default Logout;
```

I am exporting this function in another file and want to call if the backend returns a response about an expired token.

```
const getStockData = async () => {
    return instance.get(`/api/stock/symbols/${slug}`);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await getStockData();
      console.log(response)
      const data = response.data;
      const stockInfo = data.chart.result[0];
      console.log(stockInfo);
      setPrice(stockInfo.meta.regularMarketPrice.toFixed(2));
      setPriceTime(new Date(stockInfo.meta.regularMarketTime * 1000));
      setSymbol(stockInfo.meta.symbol);
      const quote = stockInfo.indicators.quote[0];
      const prices = stockInfo.timestamp.map((timestamp, index) => ({
        x: new Date(timestamp * 1000),
        y: [quote.open[index], quote.high[index], quote.low[index], quote.close[index]].map(round)
      }));
      setPriceInfo([{
        data: prices,
      }]);


      setStockData({ data });
    })().catch( 
      (error) =>{
        Logout()
      } 
    );
  }, []);
```

Here getStockData can return 403 if the token has expired.

But of course I get an error saying that the hook can't be used in a function like that. And I can't find a solution how to wrap or to do something similar so that this function can be called?

Comment: Can you show the complete code where you are calling `Logout`. Basically where do you want to call logout

Comment: Hooks are only meant to be used inside React components or inside other hooks, so in my opinion you have to catch the token expiration in one of your components and call your useAuth function as necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't let you initialize hooks inside of non-component functions. Instead, you can initialize the hook on the component level and let whatever function needs the hook's values to accept them as arguments.

```
const Logout = (auth, setAuth) => {
  const token = '';
  setAuth({token});
  localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
  localStorage.clear();
  logout()
};

export default Logout;





// Initialize the hook at the component level
const {auth, setAuth} = useAuth();


.catch( 
      (error) =>{
        // then pass the values from above to this function
        Logout(auth, setAuth)
      } 
    );
```